# Transferring error strings from C++ => C wrapped API (multi-threaded)

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, error-handling, thread-local

I'm currently wrapping an existing C++ library for use in Go. To do that, I have to wrap it with a C shim to then access it from Go. While the C++ API raises exceptions, and I am currently communicating error conditions using custom values in `errno`, I am trying to figure out a way to communicate the error strings from the exceptions.

My bindings are taking allocated pointers from the C++ API, and wrapping them opaquely => C => Go. Had I authored the 3rd party library, I would have been able to store the last error right on the class, but I need to associate it somewhere else obviously.

Because Go / cgo is multi-threaded, my initial idea was to use thread local storage to store the error string and allow Go to grab it through a `GetLastError()` function. The problem I found is that on OSX, there isn't thread local storage (from what I understand).

Disclaimer: My C / C++ skills are novice

How could I go about taking the error string from the exception that I have in the C++ side, and store it in a thread-specific way to make it available to my C wrapper (i.e. available to my Go bindings), short of actually resorting to returning a special struct in every one of my error-potential functions? Or is my only option really to make all of my C functions use output parameters, and a special error struct return type?

**Edit:** (thoughts raised from the suggestion of context objects)

If my C++ -> C shim wraps classes like this:

```
// foo.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef void Thing;
const char* Thing_foo(Thing *ptr);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

// foo.cpp
extern "C" {

const char* Thing_foo(Thing *ptr) {
    return static_cast<CPP::Thing*>(ptr)->foo();
}
}
```

Would it be basically the same effect as a context to use a `struct Thing` that carries both the pointer and the last error message?

```
typedef struct Thing { 
    void *ptr; 
    char *last_err;
} Thing;
```

Comment: If this is your problem, then you should consider having a context object for your library in which you can store data like this. And Thread Local Storage would not solve the issue for you even if it would work on OSX. Because Go does not use a thread for every go routine.

Comment: @Vinzenz - but how do I manage the thread-specific context without thread-local storage? What if two different threads access the object and generate individual errors in different calls? Or even more common... two different calls in general generating errors in different threads,

Comment: Are all the thread platforms that you implement this POSIX thread, pthread, platforms?

Comment: @jdi Using a context object you don't need thread local storage. Thread local storage is nothing but thread specific globals. I don't know how your code looks like, but where would be the problem to create a context object for each caller who wants to use your library, where you store internally such things like the last error messages etc. And in your C API you're passing this context object as a first parameter, always. If you call from Go you can create this and manage these context objects how you need them, but this is IMHO the safest way to go.

Comment: @Vinzenz - I suppose that is slightly simpler to switch to, than output params, and custom error return type.

Comment: @JensGustedt - Linux, OSX, Windows, FreeBSD. I don't actually implement any threading logic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your wrapper for the C interface which uses a context variable. That way that you give the control of the threading problem to the caller.

Here's an untested example:

wrapper.cpp

```
#include "wrapper.h"

struct context {
    std::string last_error_message; 
};

char const * ctx_get_last_error(context_handle ctx) {
    if(ctx->last_error_message.empty()) return 0;
    return ctx.last_error_message.c_str();
}

extern "C" context_handle create_context() {        
    return new context();
}

extern "C" void free_context(context_handle ctx) {
    delete ctx;
}

extern "C" int my_lib_call(context_handle ctx, int some, char const * params) {
    try {
        lib_call(some, params);
    }
    catch(std::exception const & e) {
        ctx->last_error_message = e.what();
        return -1;
    }
    catch(...) {
            ctx->last_error_message = "Unexpected error";
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

wrapper.h

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    typedef struct context * context_handle;
    context_handle create_context();
    char const * ctx_get_last_error(context_handle ctx);
    int my_lib_call(context_handle ctx, int some, char const * params);
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I'm going with this one because I will end up either doing the context object, or, wrapping my pointer into a struct that carries the context data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your platforms are all POSIX platforms, you can use `pthread_[g|s]etspecific` to handle thread specific data. The opengroup page on [pthread_key_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html) contains an example how to use this feature.

You could create a small wrapper library that uses thread local variables if available (`_Thread_local` is part of the new C and C++ standards, C11 and C++11) and uses the pthread functions as a fallback when these are not available.

AFAIR, windows has similar functions, but I am not an expert on this.

Comment: I will have to research what will/won't limit me with windows, but at a glance the pthread set/get api seems pretty straight-forward. If it isn't a limiting factor in [Linux, Windows, OSX, FreeBSD] then I would just try this approach. Otherwise I guess the answer is to go with passing a context (or at very least a `char* err`) as a parameter to all of my C wrapper functions.

Comment: This is great info, and I tried to apply it. Discovered that thread local storage is actually not a good idea with Go (obviously completely unrelated to your answer, which is great). Calls from Go into cgo can spawn different OS threads (for scheduler reasons), thus the access from the Go side to retrieve the last error from thread local storage is usually not from the same thread where the C++ code ran and stored the value. 
I'm just going to have to go with the other suggested answer about transferring context around in the call.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to pass an extra parameter you might need to implement an IPC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) system like a queue or named pipe to pass your data around.

Comment: Hmm... the take-away for me is that I should just modify my bindings to use output params and return a special struct. It seems a lot more complicated to be managing queues/pipes associated with the creation of each new object. Thanks for the info. I will wait a bit longer to see if anyone else contributes an answer.